# Vue.js : How to trigger an action after a component unloads?

Tags: vue.js

I have this component that appends to the BODY element a div when a user clicks on it. When the component unloads on page change through Vue-router I want to delete this appended div. Is there a specific method that I can use within the component to trigger a dom event?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://vuejs.org/api/#destroyed

```
var myComponent = Vue.extend({
    destroyed:function(){
        //do your worst!
    }
});
```

Comment: Ahhh... of course! Why didn't I see that in the doc !!  Thanks Jeff!